# Does Dual Wield drain HP?

Tags: sword-art-online

When Kirito fights The Gleam Eyes this is the first time he uses his Dual Wield ability which was the reason why he had a second sword commissioned by Liz, after he killed the boss his HP was quite low.

Before he uses it he's hesitant in using it, was this because Dual Wielding drains HP when active or was his hesitation more to do with the ability becoming more widely known?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was clear that Kirito was keeping his dual-wield ability a complete secret. Nobody knew about it - not even Asuna. This was evidenced by the fact that Asuna questioned Kirito about why he isn't using Liz's sword and suggested that he was "hiding something" from her.

So Kirito hesitated because be knew that using his dual wield in front of everyone would blow that secret wide open. But he had no choice. It was do or die.

---

Getting back to the question, there is no evidence in the anime to suggest that dual wielding drains HP. But you could infer other drawbacks such as tying up both hands thus preventing the use of a shield.

Comment: That explains his hesitation but what about his HP, did it get that low because of he used Dual Wield?

Comment: He had already been fighting the level boss for some time before he went dual wield. So it should be reasonable to infer that he had been taking hits throughout the battle.

Comment: i wasn't sure because before he uses it he's looking at his HP before his hesitation is shown, i'm sure it was above 50% (maybe even 75%) and it was higher than Asuna's

Comment: screenshot would resolve it

Comment: I can check when I get home. I don't have access to my anime collection from work.

Comment: His HP was going down not because of the dual wield ability but because despite his speed while using it the boss was still able to hit him.  You can see this if you look closely at the Gleam Eyes fight in the anime.

Answer (score 2):

**In the novel, there is no mention about life stealing or something like that.**

Here is all mentions about the Dual Blade skill

---

**During the fight with the 74th floor Boss - The Gleam Eyes**

> With the sword in my right hand, I blocked the demon’s blade as it
>   came down from a flame-like trajectory. Then, I reached behind my back
>   with my left hand and grabbed the handle of the new sword. I drew it
>   and struck in one smooth movement.
>
> (...)
>
> This time, I crossed my two swords and blocked it completely. As its
>   stance became unbalanced, I decided to break free from my defending
>   streak and launched a combo attack.
>
> My right sword slashed horizontally towards the demon’s midsection.
>
> My left sword followed immediately to cut vertically into its body.
>
> (...)
>
> Right, left, then right again. I swung my swords as if the nerves in
>   my brain were going into overdrive.
>
> (...)
>
> This was the extra skill that I had been hiding, «Dual Blades», and
>   the technique I was using was its **high-class sword skill «Starburst
>   Stream», a sixteen-hit combo attack**.
>
> (...)
>
> Faster, faster. The rhythm of my swings already exceeded **twice the
>   normal speed**, but it still felt slow to my heightened senses. I
>   continued my attack at a pace that seemed to overtake even the
>   system’s assistance.
>
> (...)
>
> Most of the ten-plus extra skills that had been found up until now,
>   «Katana» included, had at least ten people who used each of them. The
>   only exceptions were my «Dual Blades» and one other man’s extra skill.
>   These two were most likely limited to only one person, so they should
>   be called «Unique Skill».
>
> (...)
>
> Since then, I only trained it when there was nobody around. Even after
>   I nearly mastered it, I rarely used it against monsters unless it was
>   an emergency.

**Fight agaist Heathcliff (in the stadium)**

> I twisted my body around right before reaching Heathcliff and swung
>   the sword in my right hand upwards to the left. It was blocked by the
>   cross-shaped shield and sent out a burst of sparks. But my attack was
>   part of a two hit combo. Point one second after the first strike, my
>   left sword slid in behind the shield. It was a **Dual Blades dash-type
>   skill «Double Circular»**.
>
> (...)
>
> I just managed to guard by crossing my two swords. The powerful impact
>   rattled my entire body and sent me flying back by several meters.

**After defeating the Skull Reaper, the last fight**

> Out of the ten unique skills, **«Dual Blades» is given to the player
>   with the fastest reaction speed**(...)
>
> (...)
>
> I changed my attack pattern and activated **«The Eclipse», the highest
>   level Dual Blades skill**. Like the tips of an enveloping corona, my
>   swords sent twenty-seven consecutive attacks towards Kayaba—